# jquery/javascript: add to array in case tr has certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, push

I have a dynamic html table:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>City</td>
</tr> 
<tr class="new" id="item1">
<td><input class="names" value="John Smith" type="hidden">John Smith</td>
<td><input class="cities" value="London" type="hidden">London</td>
</tr>
<tr class="normal" id="item2">
<td><input class="names" value="Regina Mills" type="hidden">Regina Mills</td>
<td><input class="cities" value="Berlin" type="hidden">Berlin</td>
</tr>
<tr class="normal" id="item3">
<td><input class="names" value="Marcus Bell" type="hidden">Marcus Bell</td>
<td><input class="cities" value="Liverpool" type="hidden">Liverpool</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

From my js file I'm storing the information in this way:

```
     var arrayNames = [];
        $(".names").each(function(){
            arrayNames.push($(this).val());
        })

         var arrayCities = [];
        $(".cities").each(function(){
            arrayCities.push($(this).val());
        })

 params += '&names='+arrayNames;
 params += '&cities='+arrayCities;
```

With this I am getting in my php:

```
$_REQUEST['names']
: string = John Smith,Regina Mills,Marcus Bell
$_REQUEST['cities']
: string = London,Berlin,Liverpool
```

But I only need in the $_REQUESTs the values when the class in the table tr's is "new"

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just serialize the form and figure it out on the serverside, like most people would ?

Comment: Just target the `.names/.cities` within `.new`: `$('.new .names')...`

Comment: billyonecan, how can I accept your answer? It solved it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
$(".names").each(function(){
        if ($( this ).parent().attr( "class" ) == "new")
            arrayNames.push($(this).val());
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just target the `.names` within `.new`. You can use `map()` to get the values:

```
var arrayNames = $('.new .names').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

.. and do the same thing for `.cities`